# How to remove records from datatable with condition?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable like below,

```
ID--- Month---- Salary

10     Mar        15000
10     Apr        15000
11     Mar        10000
11     Apr        25000
12     Mar        15000
```

How to make this table to

```
ID-----Month-----Salary
11     Mar        10000
11     Apr        25000
12     Mar        15000
```

select distinct salary group by employee id

Comment: What data structure is used to store those values?

Comment: @sahal Do you group by ID? Your result is grouped by Salary I think.

Comment: Is this all rules to select rows? Why should you select last record from group (I suppose that is because date but explain it)? What kind of answer do you expected (LINQ, SQL, EF, other)?

Comment: I'm using c# datatable with sql, ID is Grouped